# Reading PRISM & Unity configuration from multiple files

Tags: wpf, xaml, unity-container, prism, prism-4

1. Can we have Unity configuration in file other than `app.config` file of the application? If yes, how to do it?
2. Can we combine unity configuration spread across multiple files?
3. How to define Unity configuration in the `XAML` file? (PRISM modules can be configured in XAML.)
4. Is it possible to have custom implementation of the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection` configuration reader class?

We are developing a WPF application which should allow other developers (working on various ares of the enterprise app) to register their `XAML` views (user controls) with our application. And depending on the functionality being used, our product will navigate user to the appropriate form/view. E.g. On click of the "Home" button, user would be navigated to the "Dashboard". But Dashboard may or may not be developed by the core product.

I am using `Prism` 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that pretty much everything you need is explained in the following section of **Unity**'s documentation:

- [Using Design-Time Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507504%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)

It describes how to load one or several "configurations" into a **Unity** container from the default configuration file or from several other independent files.

Based on this, I believe you should be able to have a configuration file in each of your modules and load them manually in the **Initialize** method (or the module classes' constructors). If not, you can always register the corresponding type mappings programatically in the modules too.